# Common lines between two files

Tags: text-processing, awk, diff, uniq, comm

I have the following code that I run on my Terminal.

```
LC_ALL=C && grep -F -f  genename2.txt hg38.hgnc.bed > hg38.hgnc.goi.bed
```

This doesn't give me the common lines between the two files. What am I missing there?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use `comm -12 file1 file2` to get common lines in both files.

You may also needs your file to be sorted to `comm` to work as expected.

```bash
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

From [`man comm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm):

```
-1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
-2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
```

**Or using `grep`** command you need to add `-x` option to match the whole line as a matching pattern. The `F` option is telling `grep` that match pattern as a string not a regex match.

```bash
grep -Fxf file1 file2
```

**Or using `awk`.**

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]=1; next} seen[$0]' file1 file2
```

This is reading the whole line of *file1* into an array called `seen` where the key is a whole line (in `awk` the `$0` represents the whole current line).

We used `NR==FNR` as a condition to run the following block only for the first input *file1* and not *file2* (`NR` is referring to the number of records across *all* inputs, and `FNR` is the file number of records for each individual input. So, `FNR` is unique for each input file whereas `NR` is unique for all inputs files.)

The `next` statement telling `awk` to not continue the rest of the code and rather start over again until `NR` is not equal to `FNR`, which means all lines of *file1* are read by `awk`.

Then next condition `seen[$0]` will apply only for the second input *file2*. For each line in *file2* it will print every line that was marked as present `=1` in *file1* in the array.

**Another simple option is using `sort` and `uniq`:**

```bash
sort file1 file2|uniq -d
```

This will print both files sorted then `uniq -d` will print only duplicated lines. BUT this is granted when there is NO duplicated lines in both files themselves, else below is always granted even if there is a lines duplicated within both files.

```bash
uniq -d <(sort <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2))
```

Comment: comm works fine, but in my case grep -Fxf returns: `bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long`

Comment: `comm -12 file1 file2` didn't correctly get all the common lines but `sort file1 file2|uniq -d` did

Comment: grep is faster than awk I found

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running on Linux, I suppose it's GNU/Linux and you are using the GNU `diff` command.

If you're running the GNU `diff` command, this is how to see all changed lines as well as common lines:

```
diff \
--old-line-format='-%l
' \
--new-line-format='+%l
' \
--unchanged-line-format=' %l
' \
"$@"
```

This is similar to classic `diff` output, but no file names or separator lines appear in output, and old lines are marked with `-`, new lines are prefixed with `+`, and common lines are prefixed with a space .

Here's an example shell script and the resulting output on test files:

```
$ cat diffcomm.sh
#!/bin/sh
diff \
--old-line-format='-%l
' \
--new-line-format='+%l
' \
--unchanged-line-format=' %l
' \
"$@"
$ cat > filea
a
b
c
d
$ cat > fileb
a
z
d
$ ./diffcomm.sh  filea fileb
 a
-b
-c
+z
 d
$
```

You can modify the output format for each class of line.

See `man diff` or `info diff` or the [GNU diffutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/) for more information.