# Can I use `diff` to display not the different but the matching parts?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting, diff

[`man diff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) says:

> diff - compare files line by line

So `diff` will compare the files. However, eventually, it will show the difference, if there is any. How can I compare the files and show the matching parts?

Comment: You can control the output format in GNU diff

Comment: Look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398143/338177)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output format of diff can be controlled , so for you case , you must 3 options :

```
diff --old-group-format='' --new-group-format=''  \
     --unchanged-group-format='%=' a.txt  b.txt
```

the `man diff` is not useful better read `info diff`

or use `comm`

Comment: Aaah, I always forget about `info` for GNU tools